# Moving to the next Activity without killing the previous one

Tags: android, android-activity, gridview, activity-lifecycle

I have got an activity where i download images from a server and display them in a gridView. 
Then If i click on one of those images I open a new Activity where I display the full screen image. Now if I get back to the first activity, the one with the gridView, images are downloaded again. 
I am using Picasso for displaying images either in the gridView and in the following activity. 
Is there a way to avoid the downloading of the whole set of images in the gridView EVERY time I go back from the second activity?

Comment: You need to save the downloaded images locally (In storage or cache) and load the downloaded images from there.

Comment: Save a boolean preference once downloaded. At the beginning of the downloading Activity, only download the images if it is false. Then you'll ask: "How do I read and save Preferences?". And then I'll kill you... ;)

Answer (score 0):

When picasso download an image it saves it to the heap memory, if the images is too large for the heap they are not cached. So if you have grid view full of images, use picasso's ".resize()" to down scale those images and ".config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)" to use 16 bit colors (you won't see a difference in the quality, but there is significant difference in size).

Ex: `picasso.load(url).resize(200, 200).config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).into(target);`